# Exception 0x8000500F raised when trying to create a Virtual Directory in IIS using C#

Tags: c#, iis

I am trying to programmatically create a Virtual Directory in IIS using C#

Here is a sample of the code

```
DirectoryEntry iisVDir = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/Root/main");
DirectoryEntry configVDir = iisVDir.Children.Add("config", "IIsWebVirtualDir");
configVDir.CommitChanges();
```

However, when run the code I get the following error on second line

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000500F
```

However, when I try repeating the code, but creating the virtual directory under the **Root** folder, as opposed to **Root/main** it works. The **main** folder does exist, and I can manually add a Virtual Directory under it via the IIS Management Console in Windows.

When I run the code through the debugger I spotted that the iisVDir DirectoryEntry has a SchemaClassName of **IISObject** and not **IISWebDirectory** as I would expect. I repeated the above code for another existing folder which was an **IISWebDirectory** and not an **IISObject** and it worked.

I know you can change **IISWebDirectory** to an **IIsWebVirtualDir**, but can you change an **IISObject** to a **IISWebDirectory**?

I am running IIS 5.1 on Windows XP.

EDIT: I have recreated how the 'main' folder was set up.

1. In Windows Explorer, create a new folder, called **maintest** for example, under C:\inetpub\wwwroot
2. In the IIS Management Console, navigate to this new folder, right-click it to bring up the context menu, and create a new Virtual Directory under it, called **config** for example (I pointed it to C:\Temp in my case)
3. When trying to create a Virtual Directory under the new **maintest** folder though, using the above code sample, the **maintest** folder appears to be an **IISObject**

So, maybe it being an IISObject is valid, but how do I create a Virtual Directory under it programmatcilly?

Comment: Did you try googling the HRESULT code? Apparently it has something to do with DS schema violations.

Comment: Yes, I did but it didn't really give the answer I was looking for because the code works when the parent folder is a WebDirectory. It is only when the parent is this IISObject that is goes funny.

Comment: Funky. That does sound like a schema violation though - adding stuff where you aren't supposed to - but that's rather generalized. Probably one of those errors where there are as many specific solutions as there are people who have issues...

Comment: It works when I add the virtual directory in IIS, so it is a valid location in which to create the virtual directory, which is the odd thing. If all else fails, I could manually delete and re-add the 'main' folder, to see it that makes it a proper IISWebDirectory, but I am still keen to find the cause of the error first.

Comment: Somehow, 'main' has become an IISObject, rather than an IISWebDirectory... how was it added in the first place?

Comment: It was a few years ago, I fear, so I really can't remember.

Comment: Recreating is probably your best bet, at the moment. Overcome and move on. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have partly worked out a solution for creating the virtual directory.

As described in the edit, the issue occurred when trying to add Virtual Directory to a folder that is stored in the IIS metabase as IISObject.

I think what is happening is that when you add a virtual directory under a normal 'windows' folder using the IIS management console, the windows folder needs to be added to the metabase too, but it won't have any of its own properties. I believe this is why it gets added as an **IISObject**. If you were to go into IIS managemenet console, and set some properties for the folder, then it becomes a **IISWebDirectory**.

The way I found I could add a virtual directory to my **main** folder whilst it was still an **IISObject** though was to add the virtual directory as a child of the root folder, but change the virtual directory name to include the **main** folder in its name, like so

```
DirectoryEntry iisVDir = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/Root");
DirectoryEntry configVDir = iisVDir.Children.Add("main/config", "IIsWebVirtualDir");
configVDir.CommitChanges();
```

When you specify a path in the Virtual Directory, it does appear to add the Virtual Directory under the relevant folder, and not the root folder, which is what I required.

Answer (score 0):

I have been in such a situation in ASP.NET. I passed a long debugging of these COM errors, which I had seen time ago.

In my case, when you create such a changes in the website (application) directory it causes an immediate restart of itself. This functionality is added in order for the application/website to dispose with the latest content, as I read then.

You can test and locate it by moving the target dir outside the current website, by this you will know the problem source - so you will need to implement the target outside current website (I have fixed my problem with two webistes), while the storage restarts the controller is remaining active.

Tell me if the COM error expires with moving the dir outside or wait some time for IIS to restart (10-20 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration compatibility is installed.

To verify:
Go to Start->Control Panel->Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off -> Internet Information Services -> Web Management Tools -> IIS6 Management Compatibility

In the list you will find "IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration compatibility" option.

If this is not installed, then install this feature then try with your code.

Best luck.

Keep smiling... :)